# Connect Web3.js to Geth in Goerli Testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3-providers, geth-debugging, goerli

I am trying to connect to a Goerli node using geth in which I have deployed a smart contract via Remix.

In fact I'm trying to call the function of this smart contract which returns a value for example "Hello Worlds".

This my very simple solidity smart contract deployed on Goerli Testnet:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;
contract Testnet{
  function GenerateString() view public returns(string memory)
    {
       return "Hello Worlds";
    }    
}
```

I tried this command for start a geth node to sync  Goerli and provide http api:

```
geth --goerli --syncmode full --http --http.corsdomain "*" --http.port 3334 --http.api eth,net,web3
```

And this is my javascript file :

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const abi = require("./abi.js");
const contractAddress = "0x6660697Dc5DD05Dd686A77702BBCb0a37004a7Eb";
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:3334"));
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
//Call function
contract.methods.GenerateString().call((err, res) => console.log(res));
```

But it does not work and returns me:
(node:10159) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
undefined

I also used this command for use websocket:

```
geth --goerli --syncmode full --ws --ws.origins "*" --ws.port 3334 --ws.api eth,net,web3
```

As well as the associated javascript file

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const abi = require("./abi.js");
const contractAddress = "0x6660697Dc5DD05Dd686A77702BBCb0a37004a7Eb";
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:3334"));
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
//Call function
contract.methods.GenerateString().call((err, res) => console.log(res));
```

But it still doesn't work

I tested using the alchemy provider via the api it works, the GenerateString() function returns the value "Hello World" but I would like to do it via Geth.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: My guess is that it is a node.js problem, not related to ethereum. Try to change the node.js version, not sure if it will solve although.